# Реконструирование кратчайшего пути в алгоритме Флойда — Уоршелла

Tags: алгоритм

Думаю сам алгоритм [Флойда—Уоршелла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0) известен всем,а вот как из полученной матрицы реконструировать кратчайший путь между вершинами? (лучше в псевдокоде)

Answer (score 1):

Если производительности не критична, то примерно так (s - стартовая, f - конечная, предполагаю что 0 ребёр в графе нет, вершины от 1 до N, D[i][j] - расстояние от i до j).

```
пока s не равно f
    цикл по i от 1 до N
        если D[s][i] = D[i][f] то
              вывести s
              s = i
              прервать цикл
        конец если
    конец цикла
конец пока  

вывести f
```